# how to calculate complement of vector space in gap

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, gap

I have a finite dimensional (but large dimension) vector space over GF(2), $V$.
I also have a subspace $ A \subset V$.
I have basis for $V$ and for $A$. I'd like to find a basis for the
complement of $A$ in $V$, $B : V = A \oplus B; A \cap B = 0$. (Note this is not
the orthogonal complement). What would be a good way to do this in gap?
If there are no built-in functions, what would be a good approach/algorithm?

Comment: Extend a basis of $A$ to a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $V$, take the vectors in $\mathcal{B}\setminus A$ and they form a basis for $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the bases given as list of vectors,
`BaseSteinitzVectors(basV,basA).factorspace` gives a basis of a complement.
This should be reasonably effective. Make sure that your vectors are in compressed form, as this will be faster.

Comment: perfect! this works great (using uncompressed vectors). How do you convert to compressed form? I tried ConvertToVectorRep and ConvertToMatrixRep but BaseSteinitzVectors failed with these.

Comment: Incidentally I also tried this where basV is full rank, but basA isn't; it still seems to give the right result. The manual says both have to be full rank. Was I just lucky or is the manual overly restrictive?

Comment: @unknown You were lucky. GAP operations only guarantee the documented functionality, not a specific implementation. Thus (in particular after future updates) it could happen that this will not work on all examples, or not any longer in the future.